# Hang when choosing File->Print; UI thread blocked in ntdll.dll!ZwAlpcSendWaitReceivePort+0xa

Tags: windows-7, printing, freeze

Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

Key problem: Choosing File->Print never reaches the print dialog.

Relevant symptom: Devices and Printers takes much longer than it should (2 minutes) to come up.

Printer is a Brother HL-2010 connected via Brother's Ethernet interface. Network printer is set up properly afaict.

Use process explorer to check on the process. Found the likely UI thread and here's its stack:

1. ntdll.dll!ZwAlpcSendWaitReceivePort+0xa
2. wow64.dll!Wow64EmulateAtlThunk+0x109a4
3. wow64.dll!Wow64SystemServiceEx+0xd7
4. wow64cpu.dll!TurboDispatchJumpAddressEnd+0x2d
5. wow64.dll!Wow64SystemServiceEx+0x1ce
6. wow64.dll!Wow64LdrpInitialize+0x429 ntdll.dll!RtlUniform+0x6e6
7. ntdll.dll!RtlCreateTagHeap+0xa7 ntdll.dll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe
8. ntdll.dll!NtAlpcSendWaitReceivePort+0x12
9. RPCRT4.dll!I_RpcAllocate+0x62d RPCRT4.dll!I_RpcAllocate+0x530
10. RPCRT4.dll!UuidCreate+0xbe6 RPCRT4.dll!I_RpcSendReceive+0x24
11. RPCRT4.dll!NdrSendReceive+0x2b RPCRT4.dll!NdrGetBuffer+0xf4
12. WINSPOOL.DRV!DocumentPropertySheets+0x25a3
13. WINSPOOL.DRV!SetDefaultPrinterW+0x5c0
14. WINSPOOL.DRV!OpenPrinter2W+0x89 WINSPOOL.DRV!OpenPrinterW+0x16
15. COMDLG32.dll!Ordinal101+0x2418 COMDLG32.dll!Ordinal100+0xb74b
16. COMDLG32.dll!Ordinal100+0xc3fe COMDLG32.dll!PrintDlgExW+0x1e46
17. COMDLG32.dll!PrintDlgExW+0x1dd4 USER32.dll!gapfnScSendMessage+0x332
18. USER32.dll!GetCursor+0x2ff USER32.dll!GetCursor+0xa4
19. USER32.dll!GetCursor+0x1a9 USER32.dll!gapfnScSendMessage+0x332
20. USER32.dll!GetThreadDesktop+0xd7 USER32.dll!GetWindow+0x3f0
21. USER32.dll!SetKeyboardState+0xbbd
22. USER32.dll!CreateDialogIndirectParamAorW+0x33
23. USER32.dll!CreateDialogIndirectParamW+0x1b
24. USER32.dll!GetWindowLongW+0x2e USER32.dll!gapfnScSendMessage+0x332
25. USER32.dll!GetThreadDesktop+0x12e USER32.dll!GetThreadDesktop+0xee
26. USER32.dll!GetThreadDesktop+0x86 USER32.dll!GetThreadDesktop+0x12e
27. USER32.dll!GetThreadDesktop+0xee USER32.dll!GetWindow+0x3f0
28. USER32.dll!SendMessageW+0x4c
29. ntdll.dll!LdrGetProcedureAddressEx+0x16d
30. USER32.dll!gapfnScSendMessage+0x332 USER32.dll!GetCursor+0x2ff
31. USER32.dll!GetCursor+0xa4 USER32.dll!GetCursor+0x1a9
32. USER32.dll!gapfnScSendMessage+0x332 USER32.dll!GetThreadDesktop+0xd7
33. USER32.dll!GetWindow+0x3f0 USER32.dll!SetKeyboardState+0xbbd
34. USER32.dll!CreateDialogIndirectParamAorW+0x33
35. USER32.dll!CreateDialogIndirectParamW+0x1b
36. kernel32.dll!GetCurrentActCtx+0x1a COMDLG32.dll!PrintDlgExW+0x454
37. COMDLG32.dll!PrintDlgExW+0x1bd COMDLG32.dll!PrintDlgExW+0x2e
38. SumatraPDF.exe+0x2f98a

A 32-bit/64-bit conflict? But I was able to print before, and don't think I've installed anything.

I ran the MicrosoftFixit for Printing, http://diagnostics.support.microsoft.com/diagprov/provision/MicrosoftFixit.Printing.Run.exe?_tenant=mats&diagid=Printing&_ext=.exe ; it didn't do anything.

Comment: Run `Sysinternals' Autoruns` and open the `Print Monitors` tab. What you have there?